# How to fetch egress Destination Location in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, data-transfer, vpc

I am trying to monitor my data transfer cost for VM's, for which I need destination location to effectively calculate the data egress cost from my VM.
I tried the following methods :

- using VPC flow logs, but destination IP's trace back to Mount View California.
- vm_flow traces the remote destination type to be NOT_APPLICABLE.

Comment: You may check your VM egress statistic in `Monitoring -> Dashboards -> VM Instances -> Network`. Geolocated traffic statistics are at the bottom

Comment: I don't have traffic from China or Australia, I can't see differences... But the monitoring is the right place for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me know if you looking for this.
[image]